# Dockerfile not being found in MERN application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-command

I know that there has been others who have asked this question on here before, however, I have gone through them and have tried the suggestions. I believe that its a complex issue because everyone's files look different and varies from the other based on placements and paths, which I am not familiar yet in Docker. Now, when I run on  docker-compose build, the program tells me that

> Building server
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "compose/cli/main.py", line
> 67, in main   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 126, in perform_command
> File "compose/cli/main.py", line 302, in build   File
> "compose/project.py", line 468, in build   File "compose/project.py",
> line 450, in build_service   File "compose/service.py", line 1147, in
> build compose.service.BuildError: (<Service: server>, {'message':
> 'Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile'})
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "docker-compose", line 3, in
>    File "compose/cli/main.py", line 78, in main TypeError: can
> only concatenate str (not "dict") to str [34923] Failed to execute
> script docker-compose[image]

I have tried placing the Dockerfile from the client to the same directory as the docker-compose.yml file to eliminate path discrepencies, however, it still says the same thing. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile
    image: myapp-server
    container_name: myapp-node-server
    command: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file: ./server/.env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - app-network
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - app-network
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myapp-client
    container_name: myapp-react-client
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  data-volume:
  node_modules:
  web-root:
    driver: local
```

Here is the Dockerfile in the client folder

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is the Dockerfile in the server folder

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine

# Create App Directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent

# Copy app source code
COPY . .

# Exports
EXPOSE 5050

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: did you mean to have `context: ./server` and `dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile` in the server's compose service? I think that's the issue since Docker should look for your dockerfile in the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1**: The issue was having an unusual path to the dockerfiles: `client/docker-mern-basic`. You can see this in the VSCode file explorer for the client paths. Resolved by making paths and context/dockerfile paths consistent, eliminating the extra `docker-mern-basic` path. See comments below.

**EDIT 0**: this doesn't solve the issue, I'll remove this if I can't find any other possible issues.

Your path for the `server.build.dockerfile` isn't relative to your context. You're providing the folder to use as "root" as `server` so Docker is actually looking for the path `./server/client/Dockerfile`.

I think your issue is not giving a path relative to your context:

```yaml
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. That was actually what I had originally and it gave me the same error. I just tried it again and same outcome

Comment: My bad, I think you said that in your post too. I'll take a closer look!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!

Comment: @kennyman335 From VSCode, it looks like your actual path is `client/docker-mern-basic` and your `docker-compose.yml` is in the root of your folder. Are you sure that the path to the 'root' of your files isn't `client/docker-mern-basic` at least for the client? Sorry, I can't tell the paths from VSCode but it looks like this could be the issue.

Comment: It seems as if the path is /Documents/Projects/react/docker-mern-basic/client/docker-mern-post.  Im not sure why it did that as i dont see the docker-mern-post directory in VScode

Comment: I found a solution. All i did was take out the folder that was holding the react app itself(docker-mern-post) and pull it into the root directory.Then I specified the path to the docker file which was in the docker-mern-post folder(the folder holding react). Afterwards, in the docker-compose.yml file, I specified the client context path to the dockerfile. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found a solution. All i did was take out the folder that was holding the react app itself(docker-mern-post) and pull it into the root directory.Then I specified the path to the docker file which was in the docker-mern-post folder(the folder holding react). Afterwards, in the docker-compose.yml file, I specified the client context path to the dockerfile. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great! It seemed like there was a weird path issue. Glad you figured it out.